# Error while adding Estonian language to solr 8.1

Tags: plugins, solr, stop-words, analyzer

I am trying to add Estonian language in solr but it giving the error **analytics: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core analytics: Error loading class 'org.tartarus.snowball.ext.EstonianStemmer'**

I added this in /conf/schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_et" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_et.txt" />
     <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Estonian"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and stoptwords too.

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Comment: I am using Solr 8.1

Comment: The [Estonian snowball stemmer was bundled from 8.2 and 9.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8891), so it isn't available by default in 8.1. Also make sure that you're not using a version of Solr that is vulnerable to the log4j2 exploit - so generally use the last version of 8.x or upgrade to 9.0 if you haven't manually patched the libraries or use a pre-patched version.